# Checking whether std::thread member of my class is stopped

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I have a class which has a std::thread member. I detach it in the constructor, and I wanted to be sure that, when the object is destroyed, the thread is stopped and destroyed too.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: don't detach in the constructor and call `std::thread::join` in the destructor.

Comment: The whole point of detaching a thread is that you do not care about it's lifetime anymore. On a side note, attributes mean something completely different in C++, I will edit your post for clarity.

Comment: @SergeyA: "attribute" is a well-defined thing in OO, and C++ does not [yet] define an alternative term.

Comment: Fundamental rule for beginners: **never** detach a thread. Detaching a thread is a feature for experts only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a class which has a std::thread member

Okay!

> I detach it in the constructor

Alright. That means you don't want the class to manage the thread any more. No problem.

> and I wanted to be sure that when the object is destroyed, the thread is stopped and destroyed too

Oh, so… huh. You *do* want the class to manage the thread? Interesting.

**Don't detach the thread.**

It is literally the anti-what-you-want-to-do and single-handedly responsible for your problem.

Comment: Yeah but I have another class which uses the isFinished() and getCompletion() of the ParallelTask object to draw things on screen while the thread is processing, but if I join instead of detach then nothing is drawn to the screen until the thread finishes...

Comment: @Heryon: Then it sounds like you're joining wrong. But detaching is just masking the problem (and creating a new one)

Answer (score 2):

Once you `detach` a `std::thread` you no longer have control of that thread.  the `std::thread` object releases it and all the resources of the thread will not be freed until the thread finishes or the process(program) exits.  If you want to stop a detached thread you would have to send a signal to it with some sort of flag(`std::atomic<bool>` comes to mind) or `std::condition_variable` to have it end itself.

If you want the thread to live with the class and then once the class is destroyed then terminate the thread then you do not want to call `detach`.  Instead what you would do is call `join()` in the destructor which stops the destructor from running until the thread finishes.  Once it does then the destructor will continue and you will know that the thread has ended and everything has been cleaned up.

Comment: @katamarayudu Sure, you could pass a promise to the thread for it to populate. when it's execution finishes.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's see through an example how can an `std::thread` be handled to be ensured that will be stopped and destroyed when the enclosure object is destroyed:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

class ThreadTester {
public:
    ThreadTester() : isAlive(true), randomNumber(0) {
        // Start the background operation.
        myThread = std::thread(&ThreadTester::createRandom, this);
    }

    virtual ~ThreadTester() {
        {
            // Stop the running thread.
            std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lk(mutex);
            isAlive = false;
            condition.notify_all();
        }
        // Join the stopped thread.
        if(myThread.joinable())
            myThread.join();
    }

    int getRandom() const {
        return randomNumber;  
    }

private:
    void createRandom() {
        std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lk(mutex);

        // Do something with 250ms intervall while the isAlive is true.
        while(isAlive) {
            condition.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
            if(isAlive) {
                randomNumber = rand() % 100;
            }
        }
    }

    std::recursive_mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable_any condition;
    bool isAlive;
    std::thread myThread;
    std::atomic_int randomNumber;
};

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));    
    const ThreadTester tester;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Test: " << tester.getRandom() << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Test: " << tester.getRandom() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I my example I hold the thread until it become stopped to make it sure it can be destroyed safely. I don't think so that detaching a thread is a good practice.

Comment: The constructor creates a joinable thread; there's no need for the destructor to test whether it's joinable.